# "please (re)run biber on the file" in VS code?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, vscode

I've looked over possible methods but the problem is still unsolved.
I followed the instruction that overleaf provides (but using VS code), I think key commands are all added:

```
% !TEX program = xelatex
% !TeX TXS-program:bibliography = txs:///biber
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{cite.bib}
```

Note that the second line is suggested adding. [see 1]
I can `\cite` the paper stored in the "cite.bib" file,
but the warning keeps showing:

> Please (re)run Biber on the file:
> (biblatex)  my paper
> (biblatex)  and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

> Citation 'casetta2013generalized' on page 1 undefined.

well, it surely can read the .bib since VS code shows a little window of reference info when cursor moves to the `\cite{}` command line.
I can't figure out what's wrong, so hope someone can help me out, thanks a lot!
[1] https://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/pvscws/biblatex_error_in_vs_code/

Comment: I am sure there's a way to do this automatically, but does it work if you actually run Biber manually as suggested?

Comment: @Ingmar hi, but how to do "run biber" in VS code? I even don't know what "Biber" is. :(

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 explains what Biber is and does. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 explains how you can make your editor run Biber for you.

Comment: @moewe according to links you provided, I found I don't have .blg file, but they don't talk about this much. VS code compiles Latex>Bibtex>Latex>latex every time, so hmm I still have no solution. But thank you.

Comment: If you really don't have a `.blg` file, this usually means that Biber wasn't run. (Or you're using some feature of your editor that cleans temporary files, which is usually a bad idea.) If Biber was run correctly, there will be a `.blg` file. If you configured your editor as in the link I gave and asked your editor to run Biber, you should get a `.blg` file. Try running LaTeX and Biber from the command line to see if that works.

Comment: @moewe I asked AI, it said that xelatex may not be compatible with biber. Then I changed to lualatex but problems still present.

Comment: Well on that count AI was wrong. XeLaTeX and Biber go together perfectly well. Can you try running XeLaTeX and Biber from the command line instead of via your editor?

Comment: @moewe ok, I turned back to xelatex and typed `biber my paper.tex`
 in VS code's terminal, then it said:
`xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

biber: extracting arm64 binary with lipo failed (wstatus=256)`

Comment: Then I tried `bibtex my paper.tex`, it said:

`This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2023)

The top-level auxiliary file: VS/FSI/Hamilton2023.aux

I found no \citation commands---while reading file VS/FSI/Hamilton2023.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file VS/FSI/Hamilton2023.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file VS/FSI/Hamilton2023.aux`

Comment: On Mac you may have to install Xcode command line tools to get Biber to run. I don't own a Mac, but several sources (e.g. https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/448#issuecomment-1577101437) suggest that you need to say at least something like `xcode-select --install` in a terminal. Running BibTeX instead of Biber will not do any good to your document since it requires Biber.